# how to install version not in package in linux

Tags: node.js, linux, speech-to-text, sox

I made a web application with Google Cloud Speech
and deploy it to Linux servers And an error occurs.

```
Audio sttInstance.recording error sox has exited with error code 1. 

Enable debugging with the environment variable DEBUG=record.
```

Google search results the solution is version downgrade (14.4.2 => 14.4.1)
However, below command results there is no sox 14.4.1 version
There are no search results, so downloading is not possible.

```
sudo apt policy sox
sudo apt-cache showpkg sox
sudo apt-cache madison sox
```

I've tried

- using debug => display console the debugging result
- I found the [sox 14.4.1 git repository](https://sourceforge.net/p/sox/code/ci/sox-14.4.1/tree/) and I git Clone to My linux server
  and add linux Environment

  export PATH=$PATH:/home/ubuntu/myApp/back/sox-code

and npm run start result Error: spawn ENOTDIR [image]

deploy: Amazon ec2
ubunt version: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

How can I download sox 14.4.1?